# How can i convert XHTML to XSD in java?

Tags: xhtml, xsd

I want to know how can i convert an XHTML doc into XSD which i can further process.

E.g. If XHTML has two input boxes, same should be converted into XSD.

Thanks.

Comment: The question looks a bit vague. XHTML is a presentation markup when XSD defines a schema. In fact, XHTML follows an XSD. If you want to convert part of an XHTML page (a form) to XSD, I reckon you would use XSL, but I don't see the point and I certainly don't see what would be an "input box" in XSD.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I am using alfresco ECM & trying to integrate an external J2ee WebApp with it.This app sends two docs as output : an XHTML having rendering info such as input boxes etc and an XML with actual data, which are input to Alfresco.Now Alfresco considers only XSD for web content creation not XHTML where XSD having a sequence of elements.So now idea is to convert XHTML to XSD so that flow can connect to mainstream.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

1. Use a tool such as XMLSpy to generate (infer) the XSD from the XHTML, and fix it manually if required
2. Manually write an XSL file to transform your XHTML in either simpler XML or in an XSD (much harder)